# Como abrir pdf con el lector de pdf predeterminado?

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, archivo

Soy nuevo en la programación de android. Ya implementé que mi app genere un documento pdf, y lo crea todo bien. El problema, quiero mandar un Snackbar con la acción para abrirlo en otra app (lector de pdf) todo bien hasta ahí, la cuestión es q al abrirlo sale para que le ponga contraseña??? Como solucionar este problema, aclarar q solo sale lo de la contraseña cuando lo mando abrir desde mi app, o sea, si trato de abrirlo desde el explorador de archivos, abre bien.
Estes es el metodo con el q trato de abrir el pdf

```
private void notificacionPDFCreado(final String nombPDF) {
    Snackbar.make(linearLayout_totales, "PDF Creado Satisfactoriamente", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setActionTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff7663"))
            .setAction("Ver", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.i("Snackbar", "Pulsada acción snackbar!");
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,nombPDF);
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Log.i("Snackbar", "" + path);
                    Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                    pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");

                    pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    //Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(pdfOpenintent,"Abrir con...");
                    try {
                        startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
                        Toast.makeText(DeudasCobrar.this, "Abriendo PDF " + nombPDF, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.i("Snackbar", "Error al iniciar activity");

                    }
                }
            })
            .show();

}
```

Comment: deberias agregar el codigo que as utilizado porque sino nadie podra ayudarte , deberias leer el tour de como preguntar , antes de postear gracias

Comment: Añade lo que tienes por favor, el código me refiero ajaj saludos

Comment: Ya añadí el código, con el que trato de abrir el pdf. Gracias de antemano

Comment: estas seguro que cuando lo generas, no le asignas una contraseña?, muestra el codigo de como lo creas

Comment: No en ningun momnto le asigno una contraseña ni nada por el estilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontre la solución, la tuve enfrente todo el tiempo, estaba tratando de acceder desde la raiz del dispositivo y por eso me colocaba el archivo como de solo lectura y con contraseña.

```
//Procedimiento para mostrar el documento PDF generado
public void mostrarPDF(String nombPdf, Context context) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Visualizando documento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Así va correctamente la dirección 
    String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Mi App/pdf/" + nombPdf;

    File arch = new File(dir);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(arch), "application/pdf");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No existe una aplicación para abrir el PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```